# Best algorithm to minimize an output value by varying input data

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I have an incoming stream of data and a set of transformations, which can be applied to the stream in various combinations to get a numerical output value. I need to find which subset of the transformation minimizes the number.

The data is an ordered list of numbers with metadata attached to each one.

The transformations are quasi-linear: they are technically executable code in a Turing-complete language, but they are known to belong to a restricted subset which always halts, and they transform the input number to output number with arithmetic operations, whose flow is dependent on metadata attached. Moreover, the operations are almost all the time linear (but they are not bound to be—meaning this may be a place for optimization, but not restriction).

Basically, a brute-force approach involving 2<sup>n</sup> steps (where *n* is a number of transformations) would work, but it is woefully ineffective, and I'm almost absolutely sure this would not scale in production. Are there any algorithms to solve this task faster?

Comment: Do you have access to the "code" of the transformation at runtime? In other words, are you just given the transformation as a black-box function, or is it in the form of an expression of some sort that you can evaluate? If you can analyze the transformation, what functions can it consist of?

Comment: @Timmy, up to 50 maybe, but I need to do a whole lot of these searches, so speed matters.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, I wrote a DSL for that purpose, and currently it generates Ruby code. The DSL consists of arithmetics, conditionals and native Ruby function calls (which may be reimplemented with the DSL I think, through). Almost all of the operations it invokes are linear, but several rare ones aren't. And they need to be taken into account as well. Function calls aren't recursive.

Answer (score 1):

If almost all operations are linear, can't you use linear programming as heuristics?

And maybe in between do checks whether some transformations are particularly slow, in which case you can still switch to brute force.

Do you need to find the optimal output?

Comment: Linear programming is too restrictive for me, see the comments on questions about transformation format, and implementing two algorithms—a linear and a brute-force one—is a costly and error-prone task. I may still use it, through, but I'd like to know if better solutions exist.

Comment: Yes, the output needs to be optimal.

Comment: Complexity can rise quite fast if you are moving into diophantic or non-linar optimization. So I would check your determining factors whether you have an NP-complete problem.

Comment: There are a lot of nonlinear optimization libraries. If I understood correctly, you are using Ruby, so check out http://rubyforge.org/projects/rb-gsl/

Comment: As I understand it, the optimal and generic (i.e. without code analyzing) approach to a NP-complete variant of this problem is equivalent to bruteforce? I'll try to make some use of GSL then, thanks.

Comment: What I meant: You might have an NP-complete problem. If so, a "good" algorithm will have runtime O(2^n) (if P!=NP) and therefore only vanishingly faster than prute force. If sth. close to optimal (e.g. optimal in 99.9% of the cases) would be good enough, you could start searching for heuristics and get supoptimal results in polynomial runtime.